# NSNumber numberWithInt crashing on numbers >= 13

Tags: objective-c, debugging, nsnumber

I'm pretty new to Objective-C. I've read through [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533355/nsnumber-13-wont-retain-everything-else-will) but I can't figure out how to solve my problem with that information.

Basically, I'm doing this:

```
NSMutableArray* array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 1];
NSNumber *n1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 12];
[array1 addObject: n1];
NSMutableArray* array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 1];
NSNumber *n2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 13];
[array2 addObject: n2];
```

Adding the NSNumber 12 to the array works perfectly fine, but adding 13 (or anything higher) does not; the program crashes at runtime (no error messages, and the stackdump file produced is completely blank). I'm compiling with gcc in Cygwin, if that matters.
I understand that this is probably related to retain counts, as in the question I mentioned above, but I don't know how to fix it. Even if I comment out the last line, it crashes... so it's crashing right at the numberWithInt call, meaning that if I add a retain statement for n2, it won't have a chance to get called anyway.

edit: Since I was asked for more code, here's the file I made in order to test this problem:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/NSArray.h>
#import <Foundation/NSValue.h>

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] )
{
    printf("1.\n");
    NSMutableArray* array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 1];
    NSNumber *n1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 12];
    [array1 addObject: n1];
    NSMutableArray* array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 1];
    NSNumber *n2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 13];
    [array2 addObject: n2];
    printf("2.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This prints "1." and then crashes, as above. Here is my makefile:

```
CYGWIN_GNUSTEP_PATH=/cygdrive/c/GNUstep
CXX = gcc
MAIN = DummyGame
SOURCES = DummyGame.m
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.m=%.o)
COMP_FLAGS = -std=c99 -I $(CYGWIN_GNUSTEP_PATH)/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L $(CYGWIN_GNUSTEP_PATH)/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
LINK_FLAGS = $(COMP_FLAGS) -lobjc -lgnustep-base

all: $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LINK_FLAGS)

%.o: %.m $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) -c $< $(COMP_FLAGS)

clean:
$(RM) $(MAIN) $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: You don't do anything wrong in that portion of the code. You need to post more.

Comment: I tried this in Xcode 4.1 and it works fine. I think its a gcc/Cygwin bug.

Comment: Post your *whole* code, if it's a reasonable size.  Post the smallest, **complete** example that demonstrates the problem.  Post how you're compiling the code (command line, Makefile, etc.).

Comment: @Jason: Enable `NSZombies` to see if you get an error message.

Comment: @Adam - I've added a complete code example which demonstrates the issue, plus my Makefile.

Comment: @Evan - I've added "NSZombieEnabled = YES;" to the main function (is this all that's required?) but there are still no error messages when it crashes.

Comment: @Jason: Try compiling with the `-zombies` flag.

Comment: @Evan - gcc doesn't seem to know what that is: `gcc: unrecognized option '-zombies'`.

Thanks for the replies so far, everyone.

Comment: Must be related to Cygwin. It works with GCC 4.0.1 on this relic Power Mac G5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try surrounding your code (which you've placed in main) with a line to create and then drain an auto release pool:

```
NSAutoReleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 1];
NSNumber *n1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 12];
[array1 addObject: n1];
NSMutableArray* array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 1];
NSNumber *n2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 13];
[array2 addObject: n2];
[pool drain];
```

Comment: Ah, that takes care of it. Thanks!

Comment: And the reason `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` succeeds for small integers is probably related to GNUstep's (and Apple's) [tagged pointer representation of small NSNumbers](http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/7872364181/tagged-pointers-and-fast-pathed-cfnumber-integers-in).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Release `array1` and `array2` as you `alloc`ed these:

   [array1 release];
   [array2 release];
2. Create and release an autoreleasepool:

   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   ...

   [pool release];