# userdata of a CCNode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, user-data

I have a CCMenuItemSprite that is instantiate to call a function:

`

```
menuControl = [CCMenu menuWithItems: nil];

//Create the buttons
for(int i=1;i<17;i++)
{
  Button *B_image = [Button buttonWithTexture:Sheet.texture type:i];

  CCMenuItemSprite *menuButton = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:B_image  selectedSprite:B_image target:self selector:@selector(generateEnemy:)];

NSNumber *Btype = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
menuButton.userData = Btype;

[menuControl addChild:menuButton];

}

[self addChild:menuControl];`
```

As you can see in the above, I'm using the menuButton.userData to pass in an NSNumber.
This is to "pass a parameter" to the generateEnemy function.

```
`-(void) generateEnemy:(CCMenuItemSprite*)sender
{
    NSNumber *Btype = (NSNumber*)sender.userData;

        int Etype = [Btype intValue];

        enemy = [[Enemy alloc]init:ccp(300,0) Type:Etype];
}
```

It crashes at this: `NSNumber *Btype = (NSNumber*)sender.userData;`
It works for number 1-12. But 13 and above, it crashes.

Comment: Format your text please. It's hard to read

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve this problem quite a while back.
It crashes due to this concept [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656902/why-has-nsnumber-such-strange-retaincounts/656935#656935).

How I pass data is:

```
for(int i=1;i<17;i++)
{
   Button *B_image = [Button buttonWithTexture:Sheet.texture type:i];

   CCMenuItemSprite *menuButton = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:B_image  selectedSprite:B_image target:self selector:@selector(generateEnemy:)];

   menuButton.tag = i;

   [menuControl addChild:menuButton];

}
```

In the generateEnemy function:

```
-(void) generateEnemy:(id) sender
{
      enemy = [[Enemy alloc]init:ccp(300,0) Type:[sender tag]];
}
```